# get offset then make position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello People** what I need is get offset for any section then make position of all sections is absolute:
the problem that all sections return with 0px of offset

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('section').each(function (index, element) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('top', $this.offset().top + 'px');
        $this.css('position', 'absolute');
    });
})
```

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#ff5b74;
}
.section-2{
    height:500px;
    background-color:#00ff6b;
}
.section-3{
    background-color:#5066e9;
}
.section-4{
    background-color:#ff6a00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section-1"></section>
<section class="section-2"></section>
<section class="section-3"></section>
<section class="section-4"></section>
```

Comment: What do you want to do actually? your question is not clear.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the position of all section must be absolute and section 2 top will be 400px and section 3 top will be 900px (400 + 500) ..etc

Comment: I am not sure why you need to have the position as absolute, if you could explain

Comment: I use it in parallax website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for each section you set the position absolute which makes it out of the flow before you change the remaining sections. so the remaining sections will ignore the space taken by this section and fill it.

That's why they all take the same top position

You need to set the absolute position after you complete setting the top position for all sections, meaning outside the loop function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('section').each(function(index, element) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('top', $this.offset().top + 'px');
   
  });
  $('section').css('position', 'absolute');
})
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ff5b74;
}

.section-2 {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #00ff6b;
}

.section-3 {
  background-color: #5066e9;
}

.section-4 {
  background-color: #ff6a00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section-1"></section>
<section class="section-2"></section>
<section class="section-3"></section>
<section class="section-4"></section>
```

Comment: but why my code is not work although I set the top value before position: absolute please could you explain more

Comment: because you are setting absolute position inside the loop function...so it set position and top section by section which causes the problem

Comment: @MoHamedHaSsn i edited my answer ... maybe its more clear

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is as soon as you are in the `each` loop and set the first element to `position: absolute;` it will lose it's height cause it is `position: absolute;` Or that's what `position: absolute;` does. It takes element out of the flow.

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document. **In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements.** [Information from here here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example#Absolute_positioning)

Sooo to accomplish you need to set the height by the height and the position of the previous element.

```
$(this).prev().offset().top + $(this).prev().outerHeight()
```

I left the `console.log()` there if you are interested to see the different values.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('section').each(function (index, element) {
         // console.log(
            // $(this).offset().top,
            // $(this).outerHeight(),
            // ($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()),
            // ($(this).prev().offset().top + $(this).prev().outerHeight())
        // );
        $(this).css('top',  $(this).prev().offset().top + $(this).prev().outerHeight() + 'px');
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
    });
})
```

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#ff5b74;
}
.section-2{
    height:500px;
    background-color:#00ff6b;
}
.section-3{
    background-color:#5066e9;
}
.section-4{
    background-color:#ff6a00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section-1"></section>
<section class="section-2"></section>
<section class="section-3"></section>
<section class="section-4"></section>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but why my code not work could I find answer?!

Comment: @MoHamedHaSsn updated just now to explain what was going wrong... let me know if that answers your question

Comment: thank you for your answer, but why it's not work in my code although I set the top first before position: absolute

Comment: @MoHamedHaSsn cause you set the first to `position: absolute;` and then the loop goes to the second element which is at `top: 0;` because the first element has `position: absolute;` and takes up no space. Then you set the second to `position: absolute;` so the first and second take up no space so now also the third is at position `top: 0;` because the previous elements take up no space

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    section {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        background-color:#ff5b74;
    }
    .section-2{
        height:500px;
        background-color:#00ff6b;
    }
    .section-3{
        background-color:#5066e9;
    }
    .section-4{
        background-color:#ff6a00;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section-1"></section>
<section class="section-2"></section>
<section class="section-3"></section>
<section class="section-4"></section>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('section').each(function (index, element) {
            var $this = $(this);

            if (index != 0) {

                $this.css('top', (Number($this.offset().top)+Number($('.section-'+(Number(index)+1)).height())) + 'px');
            }
            $this.css('position', 'absolute');
        });
    })

</script>
```